# Should I retake GRE given my situation about university deadlines?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I recently took GRE and got a score of 310 (Q164 V146 AWA3.5). I think i can really improve this score because i made a lot of silly mistakes in quant which i realised after the test. I want to apply for MS in CS at USC for which Jan 15th is the final deadline. I have 2 options:1) take the test on Jan 2nd  and send the scores to USC. Not sure whether the scores will reach them on time. 2) Take the test on Jan 10th  and miss the USC deadline. However, this will get me a better shot at other universities.

What do you think i should do?

Comment: What are the reasons against 2nd Jan?

Comment: I think it gives me a shot at USC because the deadline is 15th Jan. If the scores reach early (within 13 days), I might have a chance at the very least

Comment: those are the reasons **for** 2nd Jan. Is there any reason **against** 2nd Jan? From your question, it seems that 2nd Jan only has advantages, and therefore you should choose 2nd Jan...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, it's been a while since I had to think of the GREs. Don't you choose which Unis you want the results sent to and then an email with your score info is automatically generated after you complete the test and confirm that you still want it sent? The Uni in question should get the score the day of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any strong opinion about which date is better for you.

I also don't mean to be unkind, but you should first address why it is that you make "silly mistakes". Your question here is full of them.

But I imagine that one cause might simply be that you rush through things without taking the necessary care. The solution is to slow down a bit and consider what you write or answer before reacting.

If someone is brilliant but sloppy they may have less of a future than someone else who is competent but methodical.

But, apologies. I'm not trying to be mean or insulting.

Comment: Yes. You're correct. I do rush through things sometimes. I get your point